# Bootstrap 4 real-time form validation when filling out form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I've just looked at the form validation section in Bootstrap 4.4 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#how-it-works) and have implemented the code into my project, the code example and script implementation to trigger the validation looks great!

I was wondering whether it's possible to implement this validation as the user is filling out the form rather than when trying to submit the form?

For instance, if I have two inputs, First Name & Last Name, both of which are required, when I change to the Last Name field, can I get the validation check to trigger for the field I've just filled out?

E.g, validation on the fly?

My current validation (triggered when clicking the form submit button) is:

```js
function validateForm () {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    console.log(form.checkValidity())
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()

      // get the "first" invalid field
      var errorElements = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control:invalid')

      // scroll the user to the invalid field
      window.scrollTo(0, getOffset(errorElements[0]).top)

    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The checkValidity() function works on individual inputs too. Bind the `blur` handler to each input, and then add class `is-valid`/`is-invalid` to each input after validation...

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom validation styles
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')

    // Loop over each input and watch blue event
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, function(input) {

      input.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
        // reset
        input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
        input.classList.remove('is-valid')

        if (input.checkValidity() === false) {
            input.classList.add('is-invalid')
        }
        else {
            input.classList.add('is-valid')
        }
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})()
```

https://codeply.com/p/mzBNbAlOvQ

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) listener to the inputs, that call your function once triggered.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form input");

inputs.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("blur", validateForm));
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text input">
</form>
```

Comment: Sweet! Would there be anyway to modify this to prevent adding `is-invalid` and `is-valid` classes to all of the inputs that haven't been touched yet? E.g: right now I edit the First Name input, but because Last Name is empty, it gets given a class? as far as I'm aware, this is triggered from the parent `was-validated` class.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan H To the @Zim code; added or brought back bootstrap's default code (while allowing real-time validation) to not let form submission happen if there are invalid fields on submission. The full code looks like below.

```
    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function() {
            'use strict';
             window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var form_Validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    
                        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                              
                                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                event.stopPropagation();
                                }else{event.preventDefault(); processForm();}
                                form.classList.add('was-validated');
                            
                        }, false);
                        
                }); 
                
                
                
                //Below code to check every input field
                    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
                    var input_Validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, function(input){
                        
                            input.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
                                
                                    input.classList.remove('is-invalid') 
                                    input.classList.remove('is-valid')
                                    if (input.checkValidity() === false) {
                                       input.classList.add('is-invalid')
                                    }else{input.classList.add('is-valid')}
                                    // form.classList.add('was-validated');
                            
                            }, false);
                    }); 
                
                //End of block that checks each input field
                
            }, false); //window load event listener container
    })();// Immediately invoked function container end
```